# Replacing characters of a string by a given string

Tags: python, string

Given this string `'www__ww_www_'`

I need to replace all the `'_'` characters with characters from the following string `'1234'`. The result should be `'www12ww3www4'`.

```
TEXT = 'aio__oo_ecc_'
INSERT = '1234'

insert = list(INSERT)
ret = ''

for char in TEXT:
    if char == '_':
        ret += insert[0]
        insert.pop(0)
    else:
        ret += char

print (ret)
>> aio12oo3ecc4
```

What is the right way to do this? Because this seems like the most inefficient way.

Comment: That looks pretty much how I would do it. You can't get faster than a linear algorithm.

Comment: You can make it a bit simpler by modifying the original list, then `return ''.join(insert)` at the end.  Also don't forget to handle errors (too many replacement chars, not enough replacement chars).

Comment: @chrisaycock: While not disagreeing that this particular code is very fast - you can certainly get faster than a linear algorithm: for one thing, "linear" defines scalability, not speed; and even if we were talking about scalability, constant-time is better than linear.

Comment: @Amadan I agree that speed in a given runtime can be a small factor but for this particular algorithm, there is no better possible runtime than O(N).

Comment: @ggorlen: Sure, for this particular algorithm; I believe I did say that. I just wanted to clear it up for any readers that this statement is only true for this particular context, and "You can't get faster than a linear algorithm" is not something you can take as a general truth.

Comment: @Amadan Good points all around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over the `TEXT` using a list comprehension that uses a ternary to select from an `INSERT` iterator or from the current element in `TEXT`:

```py
>>> TEXT = 'aio__oo_ecc_'
>>> INSERT = '1234'
>>> it = iter(INSERT)
>>> "".join([next(it) if x == "_" else x for x in TEXT])
'aio12oo3ecc4'
```

The benefits include avoiding [Shlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) with `ret += char`. Also, `pop(0)` requires the whole list to be shifted forward, so it's linear (better would be reversing `INSERT` and using `pop()`).

In response to some of the comments here, list comprehensions tend to be faster than generators when the whole iterable will be consumed on the spot.

Comment: It shouldn't matter much in this case, but you can get rid of the `[]` brackets.

Comment: nice solution, and looks very pythonic too :)

Comment: And now it's the same as @sehafoc 's :)

Comment: I think I got it first, but I deleted mine haha, and I'm not sure that you are technically using a list comprehension there. I think you mean generator expression?

Comment: I can go back to popping, but @blhsing also went iter so I figured I'd jump on the bandwagon. Sorry about that--it was too clean to pass!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comments, you can use the `str.replace` directly:

```
for c in INSERT:
    TEXT = TEXT.replace('_', c, 1)
```

You can use also the regex replace for that:

```
import re
for c in INSERT:
    TEXT = re.sub('_', c, TEXT, 1)
```

see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: This is less efficient than the original method - it will be `O(n * m)` where `n` is the length of the text string and `m` is the number of characters to be replaced.

Comment: In this case development simplicity trumps runtime complexity. I really like this simple solution, however, there's no need for `re` and you can use `string.replace` instead. `TEXT = TEXT.replace('_', c, 1)`

Comment: @nicholishen thanks, I added the simple `string.replace` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider splitting the pattern string by the underscore and zipping it with the string of inserts:

```
TEXT = 'aio__oo_ecc_a' # '_a' added to illustrate the need for zip_longest
from itertools import zip_longest, chain
''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(TEXT.split('_'), INSERT, fillvalue='')))
#'aio12oo3ecc4a'
```

`zip_longest` is used instead of the "normal" `zip` to make sure the last fragment of the pattern, if any, is not lost.

A step-by-step exploration:

```
pieces = TEXT.split('_')
# ['aio', '', 'oo', 'ecc', 'a']
mix = zip_longest(pieces, INSERT, fillvalue='')
# [('aio', '1'), ('', '2'), ('oo', '3'), ('ecc', '4'), ('a', '')]
flat_mix = chain.from_iterable(mix)
# ['aio', '1', '', '2', 'oo', '3', 'ecc', '4', 'a', '']
result = ''.join(flat_mix)
```

**Speed comparison:**

1. This solution: **1.32 µs ± 9.08 ns per loop**
2. Iterator + ternary + list comprehension: 1.77 µs ± 20.8 ns per loop
3. Original solution: 2 µs ± 13.2 ns per loop
4. The loop + regex solution: 3.66 µs ± 103 ns per loop

Comment: I find this much more difficult to understand at a glance than just looping over a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterator in a replacement function for `re.sub`:

```
import re
TEXT = 'aio__oo_ecc_'
INSERT = '1234'
i = iter(INSERT)
print(re.sub('_', lambda _: next(i), TEXT))
```

This outputs:

```
aio12oo3ecc4
```